# How to use a variable in a variable in C++?

Tags: c++

I want to let num display the values of nr1, nr2 and nr3.  Any idees?  Thx!!

```
#include <iostream>
#include "../std_lib_facilities.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int count=3;
    string num;
    double nr1=111;
    double nr2=222;
    double nr3=333;

    for(int i=1;i<=count;i++) {
        ostringstream number {};
        number << "nr" << i;
        num=number.str();
        cout << "Num: " << num << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't get access to variables nr1, nr2, nr3 via vairable number.

Comment: Put the numbers in an array

Comment: there's no way to convert a string to an identifier

Comment: Any time you find yourself creating variables with numeric names like that, it should probably be an array.

Answer (score 2):

If your intent is to reference a variable through a runtime string you cannot do that. (For example in *php* you can do that with `$$variable`, in *C++* there is no that kind of feature).

The most similar way is to play with the *preprocessor*, but I strongly suggest you to avoid it because usually that kind of solutions are quite *"dirty"*.

The most simple and optimal solution, instead, is to use an array, and then access the variables with the index.

A little example:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  std::array<double, 3> nrs = {111, 222, 333};
  for (int i = 0; i < nrs.size(); ++i) {
    std::cout << "Num" << i + 1 << ": " << nrs[i] << '\n';
  }

  return 0;
}
```

There are a lots of variant of this approach, for example: you may use `std::vector` is the number of variables are not defined at compile time.

I think that will solve your problem.

Anyway just for completeness, there is another way to *"address"* a variable with a name. The principle is the same, but instead of use a numeric index you can use a string name.

This can be achieve just using a `map` or an `hash`.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  std::map<std::string, double> nrs = {std::make_pair("nr1", 111),
                                       std::make_pair("nr2", 222),
                                       std::make_pair("nr3", 333)};

  for (int i = 0; i < nrs.size(); ++i) {
    std::string num = "nr" + std::to_string(i + 1);
    std::cout << num << ": " << nrs.at(num) << '\n';
  }

  return 0;
}
```

So with the method [`at`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/at/) you can access the value associated with that name.

*Note:* if the variable name is not found and you try to access an exception will be thrown.

Answer (score 1):

The typical way to do this would be using a `std::map` like this:

```
int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, double> nums;

    nums["nr1"] = 111;
    nums["nr2"] = 222;
    nums["nr3"] = 333;

    for(int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        std::ostringstream number;
        number << "nr" << i;
        std::string num = number.str();
        std::cout << "Num: " << nums[num] << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: @Biagio Festa: thx, that does it!  The code of Galik also worked.